# IntelliJ File Template cursor position

Tags: file, templates, intellij-idea

I'm trying to create an IntelliJ file template that will place the cursor at a specific point in the file.  The live templates have $END$ to place the cursor in a position after inserting a live template.  I'm after the same functionality for a file template.  Is this possible?

Comment: also looking for this

Answer (score 19):

It's possible. First, check the "Enable Live Templates" box, then insert `#[[$END$]]#` at the point where you want the cursor to appear. The HTML4 File template uses this same variable, so you can refer to it also.

Additionally if you would like to use selection feature you can do so by defining adding the variable `#[[$MyVar$]]#` to your template.

Comment: "Enable Live Templates" checkbox should be checked to get it working.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me on Android Studio. We are talking about File Templates right?

Comment: @LangustenGustel Just checked it. It's working in Jetbrains own products (at least the 2016 series) but I can't make it work in Android Studio.

Comment: Rather than inserting the cursor, this inserts $END$ for me. I'm using CLion 2016.3. Here's the line at the end of my C++ Class file:

`#[[$END$]]#`

Comment: I can't get it to work in Intellij IDEA ultimate 2017.1 either. :(

Comment: Not working with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.2
Answer is outdated.

Comment: @naaz It is working in Webstorm 2017.1.3 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2017.1/file-and-code-templates-2.html

Comment: Very predictable and documented functionality in settings dialog.

Comment: On 2019.3, this inserts $END$ instead of placing the cursor.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it's possible. IntelliJ is only using the standard [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.6.4/user-guide.html) template engine.