# How do I place the cursor in an IntelliJ file template?

Tags: c++, intellij-idea, clion

How do I place the cursor at the correct position when generating a new class. Here's what my C++ Class Header file (under Editor > File and Code Templates - For current project) looks like:

```
#parse("C File Header.h")
#[[#ifndef]]# ${INCLUDE_GUARD}
#[[#define]]# ${INCLUDE_GUARD}

${NAMESPACES_OPEN}

class ${NAME} {
    private:
        #[[$END$]]#
    public:

};

${NAMESPACES_CLOSE}

#[[#endif]]#
```

I've checked "Enable Live Templates", as directed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499879/intellij-file-template-cursor-position). When I create a new C++ class, this is what I get in my header file:

```
...
class Example {
    private:
        $END$
    public:

};
...
```

Obviously it's just printing "$END$" instead of placing the cursor. The cursor ends up at the end of the file. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Note: Even though I'm using Clion, I've tagged IntelliJ IDEA since the functionality might be the same. For the record, I'm using CLion 2016.3

Comment: have you tried using `$CURSOR$` ?

Comment: `#[[$CURSOR$]]#` and `$CURSOR$` both place $CURSOR$ into the created file.

Comment: FWIW, the HTML, HTML4, and XHTML file templates all work as expected with `#[[$END$]]#`.